# How do you deploy Battle Gear?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

Like in Peace Walker, you eventually have your own mech and it is suggested that you deploy it for combat. What isn't clear is *how*.
Even after finishing the main story there doesn't seem to be an option to add Battle Gear to any of your combat deployment teams.

What do you have to do to deploy Battle Gear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Battle gear is only used for combat deployment missions and is automatically sent out if the mission requires it. The missions that it will be deployed on are the higher level ones - i.e. S rank missions.

This works in the same way other vehicles are deployed on the combat deployment where it specifies a particular vehicle as a requirement.

Comment: Ah OK. The wording made it sound like the player could select to send it out on combat deployment.

Comment: @PhilD. That was my understanding to start with too. Was disappointed that I couldn't select it from the vehicle list when going out on a mission..

Comment: It was likely a planned feature, but of course, there's a lot of content that didn't make it into the final game...

Comment: It would seem that Battle Gear was intended to be deployable on missions, not just for combat deployment. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfQS2TQHFXg) is an audio file of Ocelot talking about Battle Gear.