# How do I add vehicles to dispatch teams?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

So I've just completed the Battle Gear and I want to set it to work as well as add some of my other extracted vehicles to increase my teams' fighting ability.
Problem is I can't find the option to add vehicles anywhere in the interface.

Comment: They're added automatically if the mission calls for it. See this question for more details: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/238119/how-do-you-deploy-battle-gear

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to assign them yourself. Vehicle and walker/battle gear assignment is handled automatically when you dispatch troops and start the mission.

You'll see icons further down in the left hand column (your forces) when vehicles and gears have been selected to be sent along on combat deployments.

If you don't have the requisite vehicles/gears then you won't be able to start that mission.

Comment: So there's no option to sic half a panzer battalion on hapless redshirts like in Peace Walker? Lame